# Reversing a string with double and triple digit numbers with slice arr[::-1]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the data in a string, in reverse.
The snippet of code below only works for single digit numbers: ie. it flips 19 to 91 ...

```
def reverse_string(arr):
        # Reverse a string quickly
        return arr[::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    # str = return string for object input
    # " ".join() = drop [] & "" from output
    arr = str(" ".join(input().split(" ")))

    print((reverse_string(arr)))
```

What is the cleanest method of utilizing arr[::-1] for an input such as:
4
34 54 110 9

Task:
    Given an array, A, of N integers
        print A's elements in reverse order
            single line, space separated numbers

Inputs:
    N = size of array
    N = space-separated integers described

Output Format:
    Print elements of array A in reverse order
        Single space separated numbers

Example Input:
    5
    1 43 3 200 2

Example Output: 
    2 200 3 43 1

Comment: what do you mean by "cleanest method"?

Comment: Split into words, reverse the list. Doing a few simple tasks in a row doesn't make it special. Just make sure you have a good unit test. You should post your code, and if you really get stuck, we can help.

Comment: The code you've put here will not work as you described. I think you copied it wrong.

`n = int(input())` should be `n = input()` and `arr = str(" ".join(input().split(" ")))` should be `arr = str("".join(n.split(" ")))` in order to get the output you're describing.

Comment: Thank you, guys! Your comments are helpful. By "clean code" I suppose I just meant simple as possible while maintaining O(1). :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Output: numbers (integers)

With list comprehention you can transform in integers all the items of the array formed splitted the string:

```
arr = "5 1 43 3 200 2"
arr = [int(x) for x in arr.split(" ")[::-1]]
```

output (list of integers):

```
>>> arr
[2, 200, 3, 43, 1, 5]
```

### 2. Output: string

If you want it as a string, just split, reverse and join back to string

```
arr = "5 1 43 3 200 2"
arr = arr.split(" ")[::-1]
arr = " ".join(arr)
```

output:

```
>>> arr
'2 200 3 43 1 5'
```

Comment: I am new, so my upvote doesn't work yet, but your comment was extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't convert the input to an int. I am assuming that you will enter just integer separated by spaces, so the following code will help you:

```
n = input()
arr = n.split()
print(*reverse_string(arr))
```

Notice that you can inline variable `n`, so you could use `arr = input().split()`. That will save you a line of code.

Comment: Why use a list comprehension when you're not modifying `arr` at all?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, thanks good catch! Sometimes I get nervous while answering XD.

Comment: Thank you both. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the right idea but you should join the list back to a string after it has been reversed.

Change:

```
arr = str(" ".join(input().split(" ")))
print((reverse_string(arr)))
```

to:

```
arr = input().split(" ")
print(" ".join(reverse_string(arr)))
```